# How to Create a Hierarchical CancellationTokenSource?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, cancellation

In our project, we have decided to provide a cancellation mechanism for users with the help of `CancellationToken`.

Because of the structure of the works in the project, I need a hierarchical cancellation mechanism. By hierarchical, I mean that parent source cancellation causes all child sources to be recursively canceled but child sources cancellations are not propagated to the parent.

Is there such an option available in .NET out of the box? If not, I'm not sure whether registering a delegate to the parent token is enough or further considerations should be given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the implementation in [the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6c09f34947026ed988fd3013fdaa624a5fab0f26/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs#L809) for `Linked2CancellationTokenSource`, I came to this implementation:

```cs
public class HierarchicalCancellationTokenSource : CancellationTokenSource
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenRegistration _parentReg;

    public HierarchicalCancellationTokenSource(CancellationToken parentToken)
    {
        this._parentReg = parentToken.Register(
            static s => ((CancellationTokenSource)s).Cancel(false),
            this,
            useSynchronizationContext: false);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this._parentReg.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

And a demo:

```cs
CancellationTokenSource[] CreateChildSources(CancellationTokenSource parentSource) =>
    Enumerable.Range(0, 2)
        .Select(_ => new HierarchicalCancellationTokenSource(parentSource.Token))
        .ToArray();

var rootSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var childSources = CreateChildSources(rootSource);
var grandChildSources = childSources.SelectMany(CreateChildSources).ToArray();

var allTokens = new[] { rootSource.Token }
    .Concat(childSources.Select(s => s.Token))
    .Concat(grandChildSources.Select(s => s.Token))
    .ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < allTokens.Length; i++)
{
    allTokens[i].Register(
        i => Console.WriteLine(
            $"{new string('+', (int)Math.Log2((int)i))}{i} canceled."),
        i + 1);
}

rootSource.Cancel();

/* Output:
1 canceled.
+3 canceled.
++7 canceled.
++6 canceled.
+2 canceled.
++5 canceled.
++4 canceled.
*/
```

Comment: recommendation: try `this._parentReg = parentToken.Register(static s => ((CancellationTokenSource)s).Cancel(false), this, false);` - it avoids creating 2 additional objects per registration (the capture context instance, and a delegate instance) - instead, the instance (`this`) is passed as state, and the delegate will be hoisted and reused via a compiler-generated static field

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this functionality exists out of the box. Check out the [`CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource) method.

> Creates a `CancellationTokenSource` that will be in the canceled state when any of the source tokens are in the canceled state.

Example:

```
using var parentCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
using var childrenCts = CancellationTokenSource
    .CreateLinkedTokenSource(parentCts.Token);

parentCts.Cancel(); // Cancel the children too
childrenCts.Cancel(); // Doesn't affect the parent
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to extend `CancellationTokenSource` to support this behavior internally? It seems that `Token` and `Cancel` are not overridable.

Comment: @momt99 why do you want to override them? What are you trying to achieve there, that cannot already be achieved?

Comment: @momt99 no, the only overridable member of the `CancellationTokenSource` class is the `Dispose(bool disposing)` method.

Comment: @MarcGravell I was hoping to extend `CancellationTokenSource` to provide such a behavior.

Comment: @momt99 such a behavior as already exists?

Comment: @MarcGravell actually it's a bit different in terms of construction. By the way, I have posted my answer based on the linked token source. I would be glad if you could review it.

Comment: @momt99 ah, you're inverting the parent/child direction; fine - if that works for you: great